# What zoomable image viewers are there for websites?

Tags: images

What zoomable image viewers are there? By these I mean tools that one can embed in a website to let a user zoom in on and pan around a high res image, a canonical example being http://www.zoomify.com/ (see the demo on their home page).

Comments on them are welcome. I'm personally looking for something simple and cheap/free which ideally doesn't require Flash, and will accept the answer that comes *closest* to these requirements. But others who find this question may have different requirements, so all suggestions will be helpful. I have of course searched; I've found Zoomify, http://www.openzoom.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/galapix/ but none seem to meet my requirements, though I could be wrong and others may have more expert comments on these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/benlumley/jQuery-PanZoom meets all my requirements

Answer (score 1):

[Picaris](http://picarisplatform.com) is the only company I know of that also works in this space, but a lot of other platforms (media, e-commerce, content management, etc.) have this functionality built in. Adobe's [Scene7](http://scene7.com) is one that you might be able to integrate into an existing site.

Though with modern browsers, it's pretty easy to build an ad-hoc solution using JS/HTML5. And if you use jQuery, then there are probably plugins available that you can simply drop in to enable image zooming.

Comment: I can't find a zoomable image viewer on Picaris' site. Scene7 looks like something far more sophisticated than this too. Could you give a pointer to JS/HTML solutions? It seems a common enough requirement that I'm surprised everyone'd have to roll their own ad hoc solution. http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html has some good jquery options though...

Comment: Added: jQuery plugins are a good pointer: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html has some but http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/full_screen_preview/511142 is the only one that fits, and its paid and limited.

Comment: I've answered my question, but +1 for the pointer to jQuery plugins - thanks.